# Filter lines in txt files and make them http href links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What I want to do this time is get the number between the `(` and `)`, filter them out so I can put them in an anchored http href link.

text file example:

```
09:02:10 - Admin SO_Conner (1374991) teleported to player Footman_Skull_of_Reyne (1050854). 
09:02:15 - Admin SO_Conner (1374991) teleported to player Levy_Eddin_of_Reyne (1166164). 
09:02:22 - Admin SO_Conner (1374991) faded out player Levy_Eddin_of_Reyne (1166164). 
09:02:27 - Admin SO_Conner (1374991) teleported to player Valyrian_Militia_Crazymortal (1575057).
```

The link would look something like this:

```
09:02:27 - Admin SO_Conner  (<a href="?get_engine&loopup=1374991">1374991</a>) teleported to player Valyrian_Militia_Crazymortal (<a href="?get_engine&loopup=1575057">1575057</a>)
```

I have already tried doing it with this:

```
<?php

    if(strpos($line,'1374991') === false)

?>
```

But I can't seem to find a way to make it work.

Comment: *I have already tried* And where does `$line` come from, what is in that variable ?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$file = file(/* path to file */);
foreach($file as &$line) {
    $line = preg_replace('/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d - [a-zA-Z _]+\()(\d+)(\)[a-zA-Z _]+\()(\d+)(\).*)/', '$1<a href="?get_engine&loopup=$2">$2</a>$3<a href="?get_engine&loopup=$4">$4</a>$5', $line);
}
```

This should work, even though the regex pattern could be simpler. If you are sure that the structure of every line of the txt file is always the same, you could use the following pattern instead:

```
$line = preg_replace('/\((\d+)\)/', '<a href="?get_engine&loopup=$1">$1</a>', $line);
```

Comment: Will try this, it seems logical!

Comment: Can you also make it work with these characters '[' and ']' too?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? `[` and `]` instead of `(` and `)`?

Comment: '[' and ']' instead of '(' and ')'

Comment: just use `/[(\d+)]/`, or if you use the long pattern, use `/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d - [a-zA-Z _]+\()(\d+)(\)[a-zA-Z _]+[)(\d+)(].*)/'`

Comment: Doesn't work: https://gyazo.com/9e985d3d00917511363d2e80c63ae4b1    https://gyazo.com/6e29c5e3cb3b0ce038092b7a315aff39

Comment: Yes because now there are not just digits anymore between `[` and `]`. use `/[(\w+)]/`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to find the contents between the parentheses:

```
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var matches = regExp.exec("09:02:10 - Admin SO_Conner (1374991) teleported to player Footman_Skull_of_Reyne (1050854).");
```

([Regex Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LaxL81ho/))

Form the `href` with simple string concatenation:

```
var href = "?get_engine&loopup=" + matches[1];
```

Then add this attrbiute to the anchor element:

```
$("a").attr("href", href);
```

Comment: Mhh, a simple JS solution, will try.