# Filter lines with '[' and ']' in txt files and make them http href links

Tags: php

Yesterday I made a question about search for everything between the '(' and ')'.
[Filter lines in txt files and make them http href links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939730/filter-lines-in-txt-files-and-make-them-http-href-links/31940027#31940027)

If it found those two signs, it needed to put its contents into a href link like this:

Before:

```
09:02:10 - Admin SO_Conner (1374991) teleported to player Footman_Skull_of_Reyne (1050854).
```

What it should be:

```
09:02:27 - Admin SO_Conner  (<a href="?get_engine&loopup=1374991">1374991</a>) teleported to player Valyrian_Militia_Crazymortal (<a href="?get_engine&loopup=1575057">1575057</a>)
```

Code:

```
$line = preg_replace('/\((\d+)\)/', '<a href="?get_engine&loopup=$1">$1</a>', $line);
```

The code works for these signs '(' ')', but now I want it work for these signs too: '[' and ']' aswell.

When I tried putting these signs in the too '[' ']' it wouldn't work.

Any way to make it work not only with these signs '(' and ')', but also with these '[' ']'.

So it will work like this:

```
08:52:04 - *DEAD* [<a href="?lookup=SO_Conner">SO_Conner</a>] No
```

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 2):

More elegant solution:

Use a callback and a named back reference:

```
<?php

function my_callback($matches) {
    return '<a href="?get_engine&loopup='.$matches['match'].'">'.$matches['match'].'</a>' ;
}
$line = '09:02:10 - Admin SO_Conner [1374991] teleported to player Footman_Skull_of_Reyne (1050854).';
$line = preg_replace_callback("/(?'match'\((\d+)\)|\[(\d+)\])/", 'my_callback', $line);
echo $line;
?>
```

The change in the regex is to add in an or (the | character) and then the additional regex to capture the bit between [ ]

```
(\[(\d+)\])
```

This is then wrapped into a named group called match and all of that is passed to the callback function to build the link.

DEMO:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v62x-sjpy

In a loop:

```
    function my_callback($matches) {
        return '<a href="?get_engine&loopup='.$matches['match'].'">'.$matches['match'].'</a>' ;
    }

    //assuming you have each line as an item in an array called $lines
    foreach ($lines as $key=>$line) {
        $lines[$key] = preg_replace_callback("/(?'match'\((\d+)\)|\[(\d+)\])/", 'my_callback', $line);
    }

    print_r($lines);
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. <?php
$line = '09:03:05 - *LOCAL* [Valyrian_Militia_Doniel] conner';
$line = preg_replace('/\((\d+)\)/', '<a href="?get_engine&loopup=$1">$1</a>', $line);
$line = preg_replace('/\[(\d+)\]/', '<a href="?get_engine&loopup=$1">$1</a>', $line);
echo $line;

Comment: I have updated my answer with a better solution using preg_replace_callback and names backreferences in the regex.

Comment: Is it possible to make this work for a while loop? :/

Comment: Yes it would work in  loop no problem. I've updated the answer to show loop example.